# задать формат ячейки при записи to_excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

при записи даты в файл excel информация распознается как текст. как изначально задать формат записи даты?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
for d, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for f in files:
        full_name = path.join(d, f)
        if path.isfile(full_name):
            time_info = [(fn(full_name)) for fn in (path.getatime,     path.getmtime, path.getctime)]
            dict1 = [datetime.fromtimestamp(time_info[0]).strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'), datetime.fromtimestamp(time_info[0]).strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')]
        dict2.append(dict1)
        df = pd.DataFrame(dict2, columns=('время последнего доступа', 'время последнего доступа'))
df
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('listdir1.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter',     datetime_format='dd.mm.yyyy', date_format='dd.mm.yyyy')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
writer.save()
```

результат тот же, что у меня на картинке, т.е. excel видит информацию как текст

Comment: Приведите тестовый пример вашего DataFrame. Какие типы у вашего DF?

Comment: а в каком формате вы бы хотели писать в Excel?

Comment: как в примере с 2й по 4 строчку. они преобразуются только после редактирования, а так по умолчанию в excel пишется текст как в примере в остальных ячейках

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример:

```
In [28]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2017-01-01', freq='99999S', periods=10)})

In [29]: df
Out[29]:
                 Date
0 2017-01-01 00:00:00
1 2017-01-02 03:46:39
2 2017-01-03 07:33:18
3 2017-01-04 11:19:57
4 2017-01-05 15:06:36
5 2017-01-06 18:53:15
6 2017-01-07 22:39:54
7 2017-01-09 02:26:33
8 2017-01-10 06:13:12
9 2017-01-11 09:59:51

In [30]: writer = pd.ExcelWriter('c:/temp/test_date.xlsx',
    ...:                         engine='xlsxwriter',
    ...:                         datetime_format='dd.mm.yyyy',
    ...:                         date_format='dd.mm.yyyy')
    ...:

In [31]: df.to_excel(writer, index=False)

In [32]: writer.save()
```

Результат (`c:/temp/test_date.xlsx`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Рекомендую также ознакомиться с [Working with Python Pandas and XlsxWriter](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html) от автора XlsxWriter

Comment: что я не так делаю?

Comment: @АлександрКудрявцев, я мысли читать пока не научился, хотя и работаю в этом направлении ;-)

Comment: я поправил код по вашему примеру (добавил в вопросе). все равно excel все "видит" как текст

Comment: @АлександрКудрявцев, странно, у меня все правильно отрабатывает - смотрите обновленную картинку...

Comment: @АлександрКудрявцев, какие у вас версии Pandas и XlsxWriter? `print(pd.show_versions())`

Comment: pandas: 0.19.2  xlsxwriter: 0.9.6

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53621/discussion-between---and-maxu).

Answer (score 0):

Применение strftime производит парсинг даты и её перестроение по заданному формату, но возвращает дату с типом object (пример = столбцы d2, d5):

```
In:
   df = pd.DataFrame([1],
                     columns=['a'])
   df['d1'] = datetime.now()
   df['d2'] = datetime.now().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
   df['d4'] = pd.to_datetime(datetime.now().strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
   df['d5'] = datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
   df['d6'] = pd.to_datetime(datetime.now().strftime('%d.%m.%Y  %H:%M:%S'))
   df
Out:    a   b   c   d1                          d2          d4          d5          d6
    0   1   2   3   2023-10-04 16:02:04.499795  10/04/2023  2023-04-10  04.10.2023  2023-04-10 16:02:04

In: df.dtypes
Out: 
    a              int64
    d1    datetime64[ns]
    d2            object
    d4    datetime64[ns]
    d5            object
    d6    datetime64[ns]
```

Именно тип object при экспорте идентифицируется не как дата, а как текст.
Необходимо либо к дате применять pd.to_datetime (примеры выше - столбцы d4, d6), либо не использовать strftime (пример - d1).

При экспорте в Excel даты в столбцах с форматом datetime64[ns] даты идентифицируются корректно и без указания параметров date_format / datetime_format:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]